# Tryton: how get filtered list in wizard

Tags: tryton

Selected items I can access with `Transaction().context['active_ids']`.
However, I need access all items in list view, which match applied filter.
 Example I filter invoices by status and date in list view.
 Then, I need apply some actions in wizard to all these invoices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in tryton, you should use the active_ids keyword to access the selected records, so the user has to mark the records he wants to modify in the action.

BTW if you want to perform a search depending on the criterias the user enter, you can use a [StateView](http://doc.tryton.org/4.0/trytond/doc/ref/wizard.html?highlight=stateview#stateview) to add a form which ask the filter criterias on the screen and then perform the search based on the first view information. If you do so, this wizard should not be linked to any action but should be called by an action menú.